# React Navigation, Please attach a method to this component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to navigate to a route using onPress, but get the error: **Please attach a method to this component** I need the whole component clickable, button and text - is that possible?

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.widgetCont}
  onPress={() => navigate(AppRoutes.Settings.Name)}
>
  <Text style={styles.widgetText}>{setupRemindersDescription}</Text>
  <Button
    title={setupRemindersLabel}
    buttonStyle={[buttons.primarySpace, styles.widgetBTN]}
    titleStyle={buttons.smallTitle}
  />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This doesnt give me the error and navigates fine:

```
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={VehicleStyles.widgetCont}
    onPress={async () => {
      const success = await tryBiometrics();
      if (success) {
        Linking.openURL(BookRepairUrl);
      }
    }}
  >
    <Button
      title={myVehicles.booknow}
      buttonStyle={[buttons.primarySpace, VehicleStyles.widgetBTN]}
      titleStyle={buttons.smallTitle}
    />
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: why you took the button in touchableopacity?

Comment: You don't have onPress action for Button component. Remove this button, I'm sure, that it's not needed here, because you are using TouchableOpacity

Comment: I need the whole component clickable, button and text - is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

`I need the whole component clickable, button and text - is that possible?`

for that you can use `Pressable` from `react-native`.